# Error when running Move-SPSite in SharePoint 2010 to move site collections

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, filestream

I have a fresh install of SharePoint 2010 in a new server. I am trying to reorganize the site collections into multiple content database for easier management. I get the following error when trying to move site collections using PowerShell:

Move-SPSite : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
At line:1 char:12
+ Move-SPSite <<<<  https://xxxxx.xxx/test/test-erick/
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletMoveSite:
   SPCmdletMoveSite) [Move-SPSite], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMoveSite

Both source and destination content databases have filestream enabled. I do not want to do a shallow copy but don't know if the filestream setting is causing the problem.

UPDATE: I tried creating a content database which does not have filestream enabled and was able to move the site collection. So the problem is trying to move site content to a file stream enabled database.

UPDATE 2: I can't move the sites again so it was not related with filestream after all. I tried recreating the database and I am getting an error this time.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. The original content database I'm trying to copy site collections from was from our old farm which is pre-SP1 and the new farm has SP1 installed.

There are changes in the schema of content databases and the move-spsite cmdlet is probably referring to tables (e.g., allsites) that don't exist on the old content database.